# How to use action return value in javascript(oncomplete)?

Tags: java, javascript, jsf-2, primefaces

I have a commandButton and I want to call a javascript function when it is completed. the problem is I have to use the return of the action method in the oncomplete function. I assumed that I can use an attribute like this:

```
<p:commandButton value="پیش نمایش گزارش" ajax="true" id="showReport" update=":panel 
showReport" action="#{reportUIBean.showReport()}" oncomplete=
"if(#{reportUIBean.successful}){dialog.show();}" process="@this" />
```

The problem with this is although the update runs before the oncomplete function but it wont work properly. I think it is because the function is already in command stack.
I tried another way by using onsuccess but will always call the function because I have to catch the exceptions. is there any way to call a javascript function and use a JSF value in it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This just solved my problem:

```
<p:commandButton value="پیش نمایش گزارش" ajax="true" id="showReport"
    update=":panel show" action="#{reportUIBean.showReport()}" 
    oncomplete="document.getElementById('reportOptions:show').click();"
    process="@this" />

<p:commandButton style="display: none" id="show"
    onclick="if(#{reportUIBean.successful}) {dialog.show();}"/>
```

I know its not a fancy way but it works...

Answer (score 4):

You can add Callback param using [Primefaces RequestContext](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/requestContext.jsf) in your action....

*Bean*

```
 public void showReport() {
     // generate report
     RequestContext context = RequestContext.getCurrentInstance();  
     context.addCallbackParam("successful", true);    //if okay to show dialog
 }
```

*Button*

```
<p:commandButton value="پیش نمایش گزارش" 
                id="showReport" 
                update=":panel showReport"
                action="#{reportUIBean.showReport()}" 
                oncomplete="handleComplete(xhr, status, args)"
                process="@this" />
```

*JS*

```
function handleComplete(xhr, status, args) {  
   if(args.successful) {  
       dialog.show();
    }      
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This has been changed to `PrimeFaces.current().ajax().addCallbackParam(...)` in more recent versions of PrimeFaces